# Altium schematic symbol weird behavior when rotated

Tags: schematics, altium, software

Hi I am not new to Altium however I am facing a problem that I think is in the 2020/2021 versions.

the problem is that schematic symbols drawn using IEEE symbols (inverter in this example) is working weirdly (the triangle is mirrored) when rotated 90 degrees as the following images show

[image]

[image]

Note 1: this behavior exist in the schematic library and in the documents as well.

Note 2: the small triangles are also inverters from same IEEE library.

Note 3: this component maybe is drawn in old versions (2018) if that matters.

Comment: It is a small symbol. Delete it and draw it again. Somehow it is rotating the big triangles independently from everything else I guess but I don't know why.

Comment: The latest version of Altium (v21) has lots of bugs. It takes a year for a major version change to become useful. Try using a previous version in the version 18 to 20 range..

Comment: I wish companies didn't feel the need to redo their code base and UI every 3-5 years, they end up breaking things and the users suffer. And all to show the users that they are actually doing 'something' to justify their license fees. I'd rather see them reduce their fees and work on features that are useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what is causing the problem : when this component was drawn the "triangles" where drawn the "X" key was used for rotating them (mirror) .

To correct the problem I entered the schmatic library then mirrored them. then I rotated them by space key or entering the rotation in degrees (properties menu) .

This solved the issue, However it is still weird and un-explainable bug.

Hope this helps someone else